# Find next array index with true value C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of booleans like this:

```
bool arr[] = { false, true, false, false, false, true };
```

I implemented an algorithm to find the next `true` value depending on the current index:

```
bool isNewRound = false;

int get_next_true(int index) {
    for(int i=index + 1; i<arr.size(); i++) {
        if (arr[i]) {
            return arr[i];
        }
    }
    
    isNewRound = true;

    for(int i=0; i<index; i++) {
        if (arr[i]) {
            return arr[i];
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

I don't like my solution, because it uses two loops instead of one. I was thinking about using a `while` loop but in this case it requires an internal counter.

I need some optimization for the current solution, if that's possible, and maybe some suggestions on how to improve my approach.

P.S. It would be nice if I could detect that I already reached the end of the array.

Thank you

Comment: Have you heard of the modulo operator?

Comment: something like `for(int i=index + 1; i != index; i = (i+1) % arr.size())`

Comment: @ThePhilomath looks awesomely working.. but can I also detect with bool that I have reached end of array once?

Comment: I don't understand whether you want to return the **index** of the next true value or that true value (why? it's literally *always* true) or something else.

Comment: `return arr[i];` should be `return i;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Time complexity of your approach is O(n)

---

### Query in time complexity O(1) solution

```
const int n = 6;
bool arr[n] = { false, true, false, false, false, true };
int next_index[n];

int get_next_true(int index) {
  return next_index[index];
}

int main() {
  int true_index = -1;
  for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    next_index[i] = true_index;
    if (arr[i] == true)
      true_index = i;
  }
  for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (next_index[i] == -1)
      next_index[i] = true_index;
    else
      break;
  }
  printf("%d\n", get_next_true(2));
}
```

---

### Query in time complexity O(log<sub>2</sub>n) solution

You can maintain the prefix sum of `arr` (consider `true` as value 1) and then use binary search to find the index of the next true value.

A simple demonstration:

```cpp
const int n = 6;
bool arr[n] = { false, true, false, false, false, true };
int prefix[n];
bool isNewRound = false;

int get_next_true(int index) {
  int pos = std::upper_bound(prefix + index + 1, prefix + n, prefix[index]) - prefix;
  if (pos != n)
    return pos;
  isNewRound = true;

  pos = std::upper_bound(prefix, prefix + index + 1, 0) - prefix;
  if (arr[pos] == false)
    return -1; // Not Found

  return pos;
}
```

Also, remember to do some pre-processing before calling `get_next_true`:

```cpp
prefix[0] = arr[0];
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  prefix[i] = arr[i] + prefix[i - 1];
}
```

---

### Query and modify an element in time complexity O(log<sub>2</sub>n)

Note that if `arr` is not a fixed array (You may want to modify it), you will need to use some data structure like [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree).

Comment: Any reason why you guys gave it downvote? Since it is 100% correct and faster

Comment: Though i didn't down voted you but lemme explain why others did. Whenever you give  answer , try to provide a minimal example so that others can get what you are trying to say. Don't provide the whole solution just the crux of your answer. After all this ain't a theory class. P.S. I upvoted this. :-)

Comment: Why is `prefix` array never filled?

Comment: @Croolman I added some explanation for that part, please check:D

Comment: 1) It will be faster only if an array is long enough. 2) We have algorithms `std::partial_sum` and `std::lower_bound`, there is no need to write your own. 3) Repeating `6` three times is a bad thing to do. Use `constexpr` for `n`, and then write `arr[n]`.

Comment: @Evg I appreciated your suggestions, the code looks more concise now! And indeed O(logn) is not going to be faster that O(n) when `n` is only 6. But it is going to be faster when `n` is larger than 10 or something like that :D

Comment: As it was noted before, it would be nice to use `std::partial_sum` to fill the prefix array. Additionally, I would have preferred using `std::array`.
And I want to note that an array of partial sums might be an overshoot, as we can just store an array of indices where true values are. Time complexity will be O(1), and the pre-processing is also O(N) as in your solution.

Comment: Can I use partial_sum with bool array? On my computer the output of prefix after `std::partial_sum(arr, arr + n, prefix);`  is `0 1 1 1 1 1`

Comment: @ValeriySavchenko I think the time complexity is still O(logn) since you still need to binary search the index that is greater than the given index. But your idea is actually more straight forward!

Comment: @StillFantasy I added my solution below. It couldn't be a O(logN) because I don't search for anything, just iterate through an array.

Comment: @Evg Generally, if the array is small, we don't care, not with the current CPU's :) Well not if the loop itself is in tight loop of course, but generally speaking ...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I think we [do care](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJJTYQYB1JQ). Not always. After edit: agree.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the posted code intent, but if the task is

> Find next array index with true value

A simple solution (testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PCKVrRgLcv0xOZvd)) could be

```
template <class It>
constexpr size_t find_index_of_next_true(It first, It last, size_t index)
{
    size_t size = std::distance(first, last);
    return size <= index
        ? size
        : std::distance(first, std::find(first + index + 1, last, true));
}
```

Which is O(N), of course, as that is the time complexity of [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), but the OP didn't mention how big their array is.

Answer (score -1):

## Time complexity O(1) with O(N) extra space

First, we can store all the indices where the array holds true values and thus have a constant time access to the next index. Pre-processing (constructing an array of indices) still takes linear time, so this approach makes sense when you want to iterate through your *true* indices many times.

This code shows a static version, while dynamic will require O(N) time to modify values in the array.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <vector>

template <unsigned N>
class BoolArray {
public:
  using true_iterator = std::vector<unsigned>::const_iterator;

  BoolArray(std::array<bool, N> &&Init) : Data(std::move(Init)) {
    init();
  }

  true_iterator tbegin() const {
    return TrueValues.begin();
  }

  true_iterator tend() const {
    return TrueValues.end();
  }

  bool operator[](unsigned Index) {
    return Data[Index];
  }

private:
  void init() {
    TrueValues.reserve(N);
    // O(N) time to pre-process the data
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      if (Data[i]) {
        TrueValues.push_back(i);
      }
    }
  }

  std::array<bool, N> Data;
  // extra O(N) space for fast fetching of the next index
  std::vector<unsigned> TrueValues;
};
```

## Time complexity O(N) with O(1) extra space

This is a more straightforward approach. Iterate further where we left off and iterate all the way till the end.

Implemented iterator is only a prototype and can be implemented to be bidirectional.

```cpp
#include <array>

template <unsigned N>
class BoolArray {
public:
  BoolArray(std::array<bool, N> &&Init) : Data(std::move(Init)) {}

  class true_iterator : public std::forward_iterator_tag {
  public:
    true_iterator(const true_iterator &) = default;
    true_iterator &operator=(const true_iterator &) = default;
    true_iterator(true_iterator &&) = default;
    true_iterator &operator=(true_iterator &&) = default;

    unsigned operator*() const {
      // O(1) for random-access iterators, which is true for
      // array iterators (it's just a difference between indices)
      return std::distance(Data.begin(), Iterator);
    }

    true_iterator &operator++() {
      ++Iterator;
      skipFalseValues();
      return *this;
    }
    true_iterator &operator++(int) {
      true_iterator tmp(*this);
      operator++();
      return tmp;
    }

    bool operator==(const true_iterator& rhs) const {
      return Iterator == rhs.Iterator;
    }
    bool operator!=(const true_iterator& rhs) const {
      return Iterator != rhs.Iterator;
    }

  private:
    using UnderlyingIterator = typename std::array<bool, N>::const_iterator;

    void skipFalseValues() {
      // O(N) time to find next true element
      for (;Iterator != Data.end() and not *Iterator; ++Iterator) {};
    }

    friend class BoolArray<N>;
    true_iterator(const std::array<bool, N> &Data, UnderlyingIterator Current)
      : Data(Data), Iterator(Current) {
      skipFalseValues();
    }

    const std::array<bool, N> &Data;
    UnderlyingIterator Iterator;
  };

  true_iterator tbegin() const {
    return {Data, Data.begin()};
  }

  true_iterator tend() const {
    return {Data, Data.end()};
  }

  bool operator[](unsigned Index) {
    return Data[Index];
  }

private:
  std::array<bool, N> Data;
};
```

## Test

In both cases, the following code:

```cpp
int main() {
  constexpr unsigned Size = 6;
  BoolArray<Size> TestArray{ {false, true, false, false, false, true} };
  for (auto It = TestArray.tbegin(), End = TestArray.tend(); It != End; ++It) {
    std::cout <<
      (TestArray[*It] ? "true" : "false") << " at index " << *It << std::endl;
  }
}
```

produces this output:

```
true at index 1
true at index 5
```